# Mysql extractvalue function to retrieve xml snippet from xml content

Tags: php, mysql, xml

My xml content "CommandDefinition" =

```
<command category="213" id="3" type="om">
    <name>CMD_1</name>
    <description>this is the desc</description>
    <parameter pos_index="1">
        <description>device index</description>
        <state>1</state>
    </parameter>
</command>
<command category="213" id="4" type="om">
    <name>CMD_2</name>
    <description>This parameter belongs to FAPService.{i}.Capabilities.</description>
    <parameter pos_index="1">
        <description>device index</description>
        <state>1</state>
        </parameter>
</command>
```

I am trying to retrieve entire node value of command tag,  where name attribute holds value "CMD_2".  i.e. retrieve value should look like:

```
<command category="213" id="4" type="om">
    <name>CMD_2</name>
    <description>This parameter belongs to FAPService.{i}.Capabilities.</description>
    <parameter pos_index="1">
        <description>device index</description>
        <state>1</state>
        </parameter>
</command>
```

I tried following:

ExtractValue(CommandDefinition, '//command[name= "CMD_2"]')

But this returns me an empty string instead. Any thought on this? Thx

Comment: It returns an empty string because `//command[name= "CMD_2"]/text()` is an empty string (whitespace only). The `/text()` at the end is implicity, see the Mysql manual.

Comment: I have updated my question with more clarity. I am not interated is value or text part instead would like to retrieve entire xml tag content of "command" along with its child node contents.

Comment: You can't. `ExtractValue` is always the said `/text()`. You're using the wrong tool for the job. Please take a look in the manual and educate yourself about this function. It's not going to work how you outline it in your question. Most likely you've done a wrong guess, which does not qualify as a programming question. Please edit your question and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This link is really helpful: 
click here! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71336/MySQL-XML-User-Defined-Functions?